# UIAlertController not showing anything

Tags: ios

My UIAlertController isn't showing but the code looks correct.

```
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Lorem"
                                                                             message:@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sed ultrices nisl."
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just answering my own question because I lost an hour on this and want to save somebody else the headache.*

Make sure that you are not calling this code from viewDidLoad, if you need it that early in the viewController then call it from viewWillAppear.